# Нужна ли база данных?

Tags: база-данных

Как определить нужна ли моей программе база данных?
Храню данные в XML файлах, которые обновляются примерно раз в час. В каждом файле строк по 20 где то. Причем файлов не больше 3000. Есть ли смысл прикручивать БД?

Comment: Если не секрет, какие именно данные вы храните в 3000 XML-файлов?

Comment: Данные о клиентах компании.
Серверная часть существует, клиент читает данные раз в час.

Comment: Судя по количеству XML, смахивает на клиент какого-нибудь ozon.ru, который свои данные в XML и предоставляет (не считая адекватного обращения через сервисы)

Comment: нет, это не ozon)

Comment: Не приходила мысль реализовать, например, веб-сервис?

В общем-то всё зависит от того, насколько сложные действия с данными из XML производятся...

Comment: Необходимо именно клиент-серверное приложение. Данные на сервере изредка обновляются. И только читаются клиентом. Меня интересует доводы как раз в сторону не использования БД

Comment: В пользу БД: производительность выше. В пользу XML: работает - не трогай; не всегда данные из XML можно безболезненно перенести в реляционные БД.

Comment: Ну, хорошо, элементарный поиск по полям есть в программе? Представьте, что клиенту потребуется "живой" поиск, хотя бы после 3-х символов введённых... Насколько бы хорошо у него жёсткий не работал, пробежать по 3000 XML будет не шибко быстро... А постоянная загрузка/выгрузка тож не самое большое счастье для программы.

Comment: Для каждого клиента существует свой файл на сервере. Клиент лишь отправляет запрос в виде своего ID, сервер находит нужный файл по ID и в ответ клиент получает строку, которую сам парсит и визуализирует.
Поиска по полям нет, файл ищется по названию

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, хорошо, элементарный поиск по полям есть в программе? Представьте, что клиенту потребуется "живой" поиск, хотя бы после 3-х символов введённых... Насколько бы хорошо у него жёсткий не работал, пробежать по 3000 XML будет не шибко быстро... А постоянная загрузка/выгрузка тож не самое большое счастье для программы.

Хорошо, а что будет, если во время обновления этих самых 3000 XML будет запрос от клиента?

В общем-то гадать можно долго, что и где у Вас свалится в том или ином случае... Известно как минимум одно - СУБД это нормальная поддержка транзакций (случай с одновременным обновлением и получением данных), оптимизированный подход к множеству параллельных запросов...

Если в Вашей задаче 1 запрос от клиента в час, то большую часть проблем, которые решают СУБД Вы сможете решить и сами, но при масштабировании приложения может получиться большой велосипед...

Answer (score 0):

Это не дело хранить в 3000 файлах xml данные... Реализация поиска, сортировки весьма проблематичны, особенно если учесть, что объем данных со временем может увеличится. Заводите базу данных для этого дела. Сначала почитайте материал на какую [СУБД](http://www.osp.ru/dbms/1998/04-05/13031590/) вам желательно переходить. Изучите предметную область своей организации, структурируйте данные, входящие и исходящие потоки информации, обратите внимание на структуру ваших xml файлов, после чего начинайте проектировать информационную систему. Клиентские приложения тоже придется переписать, так как логика их настроена на работу с xml-файлами. Удачи, в разработке АИС!

Answer (score 0):

мне кажется что база данных у вас уже есть. (в виде 3000 xml файлов)
субд тоже есть (..серверная часть..)
вопрос в том как она решает существующие задачи + какие задачи придется решать в будущем..
из вопроса не понятно